# XCode 6.2 - CLAuthorizationStatus.Type does not have a member named 'Authorized'

Tags: ios, swift

My working code suddenly started throwing this error after I upgraded to XCode 6.2

ERROR: CLAuthorizationStatus.Type does not have a member named 'Authorized'

The error is coming in this line

CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:"App is Authorized to use location services.",CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse:"You have granted authorization to use your location only when the app is visible to you."]

Comment: As connor said, there are now two types of authorization, "in use" (i.e. only while the app is running) and "always". Use the rendition appropriate for your app's needs. Please refer to the documentation on [Asking Permission to Use Location Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW72), because not only have these methods changed, but there's also a plist setting you must specify (or else you won't ever see the permissions alert). Bottom line, read the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they replaced Authorized with AuthorizedAlways in CLAuthorizationStatus. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS82APIDiffs/modules/CoreLocation.html). You can also command click on CLAuthorizationStatus to see its definition:

```
enum CLAuthorizationStatus : Int32 {

    // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
    case NotDetermined

    // This application is not authorized to use location services.  Due
    // to active restrictions on location services, the user cannot change
    // this status, and may not have personally denied authorization
    case Restricted

    // User has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or
    // location services are disabled in Settings.
    case Denied

    // User has granted authorization to use their location at any time,
    // including monitoring for regions, visits, or significant location changes.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    case AuthorizedAlways

    // User has granted authorization to use their location only when your app
    // is visible to them (it will be made visible to them if you continue to
    // receive location updates while in the background).  Authorization to use
    // launch APIs has not been granted.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    case AuthorizedWhenInUse
}
```